# Flex-box Dilema

Tags: css, flexbox

I have been working on a site with a left pop open Navigation bar. I got it right to get my content to wrap with flex-box and wrap, but my #main section does not wrap when the nav bar is opened and falls off my page. Any one able to assist me with this as I am super new to CSS3.

Layout:[What the layout looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCQ4h.png)

My problem:[My content bleeding off of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZVhI.png)

Code (HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="nav.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<nav id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" 
    onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>

<section id="main">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" 
    onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
  <br>
  <section class="box-container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </section>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Code (CSS):

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
font-family: arial;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 15px;
    font-size: 26px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

/* PROBLEM ARIA */

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    width: auto;
    /*float: left;*/
}

.box {
    text-align: center;
    width: calc(33.33% - 20px);
    height: 280px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: black;
}

.box-container {
    padding: 25px;
    min-width: 97vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the HTML code we can only guess based on the images you posted, but it seems your `.sidenav`  is part of the flex container, that's why it moves the rest of the stuff when it becomes visible.

Just take your `.sidenav` out of the flex-container (`#main`)  and let it be independent from the flex stuff.

Comment: I really don't understand why answer an incomplete question like this....and the answer is simply a guess, with little, if any, value for other users